# Как передать метод возвращающий символ в другой класс

Tags: java, char

Метод по символьно считывает файл. Необходимо передать этот метод в парсер так что бы он перебирал все символы. Но так как он возвращает значение то естественно выводится один символ.

```
public char read() throws ReadException {
    try {
        int symbol;
        fileRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile));
        while ((symbol = fileRead.read()) != -1) {
        }
        return (char) symbol;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ReadException(e);
    }
}
```

Вопрос: Каким образом его можно передать в парсер?

Comment: вопрос, а парсер принимает какой-ниубудь интерфейс? нужно больше инфы, что за парсер и т.д.

Comment: Да он принимает интерфейс. Задачка такая: дан *.java-файл. Нужно перебирая символы в файле("{",";") отформатировать его. Поставить переносы и отступы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [итератор](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). Набросок реализации:

```
class ReaderIterator implements Iterator<Character> {

    private final Reader reader;
    private int next = -1;

    public ReaderIterator(Reader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (next != -1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            try {
                next = reader.read();
                return (next != -1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new ReadException(e);
            }
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public Character next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        Character result = Character.valueOf((char)next);
        next = -1;      
        return result;
    }

}
```

Затем передавайте итератор в парсер:

```
fileRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile));
ReaderIterator iterator = new ReaderIterator(fileRead);
parser.Parse(iterator); // Parse(Iterator<Character> iterator)
```

В парсере получаем символы:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    char c = iterator.next().charValue();
    // ...
}
```

Недостатком решения является то, что `ReadException` должен быть unchecked.

Comment: По сути у меня задача изобрести велосипед вроде своего итератора, однако ваш ответ позволил мне приблизиться

Answer (score 1):

Мало подробностей задачи. Но, как вариант, можно возвращать массив:

```
public char[] read() throws ReadException {
    try {
        int symbol;
        String s = ""; //тут лучше SbringBuilder использовать, String для краткости лишь
        fileRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile));
        while ((symbol = fileRead.read()) != -1) {
            s += (char) symbol;
        }
        return s.toCharArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ReadException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, натолкнуло на мысль)